# How to use CLI to start/stop openvpn that works with NetworkManager

Tags: command-line, 19.04, openvpn

Openvpn is working great under NetworkManager.  What do I need to do to run it from the command line?  I use an OTP password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find out what your VPN is *named*. Look in the TYPE column:

  ```
  $ nmcli connection 
  NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
  Wired_conn_name     dd87a04c-4a53-3414-8287-190c4c870fb3  ethernet  enp5s0 
  My_VPN_name         d338359f-447b-4be4-92ff-f3d2e7199275  vpn       --
  ```
- Start the VPN client using it's name

  ```
  $ nmcli connection up My_VPN_name
  ```
- Stop the VPN client using it's name

  ```
  $ nmcli connection down My_VPN_name
  ```